# How to handle path and arguments in Angular Routing?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've got a SPA which requires some arguments passed to launch.
The clients launch the SPA using direct link like `https://myapp.com/index.html?test=123&test2=12314` or `https://myapp.com/?test=123&test2=12314`

The SPA has an Angular Router setup with path /s/m/12345 which allows the client to open up a specific page.

I need to be able to create a direct link to the `https://myapp.com/s/m?test=123&test2=12314` page, however, I don't know how to create a direct link.

https://myapp.com/s/m/?test=123&test2=12314

https://myapp.com/index.html/s/m?test=123&test2=12314

won't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at ActivatedRouter with queryParams ? to get test and test2 as parameters..

```
    constructor(
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

this.currentTest = JSON.parse(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('test'));
this.currentTest2 = JSON.parse(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('test2'));
```

Comment: but where is this constructor in?

Comment: in your component that youa re trying to display...